# Why can't I comment on other questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, comments

I looking for a diary program, that I can use for writing things, shopping, doctor apointments, and other things for my wife and I found an answer.

But I can't ask the guy a question like other answer where you can comment.  This one has no comment available. why?

How can I can leave a comment?

Here is the question and answer.

[What Digital Diaries are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140116/digital-diaries-for-ubuntu)

Can you help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a minimum of **50 rep** to be able to comment "everywhere".

Please [see this section of the FAQ.](https://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation).

<sup>If you really, desperately, absolutely need to comment without the minimal rep -- post the comment as answer, and it will most probably be flagged and converted into a comment in a little bit.</sup>