# Can't add comments to the first post of a question

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I comment on other questions/answers?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3556/why-cant-i-comment-on-other-questions-answers)

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question to ask, so sorry in advance.

If someone posts a question I see that other people can comment underneath it, however there is no "add comment button" to be found. Quick screen cap:

[image: screen shot]

I only have 43 rep, that may have something to do with it.

I can only comment on my own answers, not questions or other people's answers. Example:

[image: screen shot two]

Comment: I think you *can* comment now, or at least after the privileges refresh operation completes on the askubuntu.com servers. When asking about the site, be sure to use [meta], though.

Comment: just in case I gave him 5 extra @ObsessiveSSOℲ :+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [comment everywhere privilege](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment) to comment everywhere, which requires 50 reputation.

You do not need that privilege to comment on your own questions or answers, though.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://askubuntu.com/privileges  it will show what privileges you have.

More info on commenting: https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment

Oh and I read just now you need 50 rep ;)